# Displaying multiple errors per field with jQuery Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am looking to use the jQuery validator plugin to display multiple field level error messages at a time.

For example:

```js
$("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10,
            alphanumeric: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        field: {
            required: 'This is required.',
            minlength: 'Please enter at least 10 characters.',
            alphanumeric: 'No special characters.'
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error) {
        $("#response").html(error);
    }
});
```

An input with "required", "minlength 10" and "alphanumeric", will only show the error for the minimum length if there are less than 10 characters, even though there may be a special character in the field.

I am looking for a solution to show all the messages for currently invalid rules on a given input field.

```
<label for="field">Field:</label>
<p>Please enter at least 10 characters.</p>
<p>No special characters.</p>
<input type="text" id="field" name="field" />
```

I appreciate any input on how to achieve this!

Thanks, 
Danny

Comment: can you give me the real url of jquery validation what has been you use.

Comment: @viyancs it is this one: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Have you tried using the `showErrors` option? Look at the `errorMap` parameter in the callback: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options

Comment: I have tried the showErrors option, but errorMap and errorList only return one error per field at a time.

Comment: It checks the validation rules sequentially so if you want it to check alphanumeric before minlength then in 'field' put it before alphanumeric. Displaying all the error messages at once could get confusing for the user imo.